# OpenCV - Thin Plate Spline

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

How to convert an image from one shape to other using thin plate spline in opencv python3. in c++ we have shape transformer class. in opencv python3 how can we implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Thin plate spline indeed exists for opencv in python3. 
You can use help function to get more info on which functions exist and how to use them like this:

```
>>> help(cv2.createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer()) ## () braces matter !!
Help on ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer object:

class ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer(ShapeTransformer)
|  Method resolution order:
|      ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer
|      ShapeTransformer
|      Algorithm
|      builtins.object
|
|  Methods defined here:
|
|  __new__(*args, **kwargs) from builtins.type
|      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate 
signature.
|
|  __repr__(self, /)
|      Return repr(self).
|
|  getRegularizationParameter(...)
|      getRegularizationParameter() -> retval
|
|  setRegularizationParameter(...)
|      setRegularizationParameter(beta) -> None
|
|  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Methods inherited from ShapeTransformer:
|
|  applyTransformation(...)
|      applyTransformation(input[, output]) -> retval, output
|
|  estimateTransformation(...)
|      estimateTransformation(transformingShape, targetShape, matches) -> 
None
|
|  warpImage(...)
|      warpImage(transformingImage[, output[, flags[, borderMode[, 
borderValue]]]]) -> output
|
|  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Methods inherited from Algorithm:
|
|  clear(...)
|      clear() -> None
|
|  getDefaultName(...)
|      getDefaultName() -> retval
|
|  save(...)
|      save(filename) -> None
```

[Source](http://answers.opencv.org/question/121616/how-to-access-thinplatespline-shapetransformer-functions-in-python/)

Comment: I am not getting. it is showing that, no module existed

Comment: what version of opencv are you using?

Comment: @RickM. in a nutshell where does one use this function?

Comment: @JeruLuke do you mean where do we use [`ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer`](https://qiita.com/SousukeShimoyama/items/2bf8defb2d057bb8b742)?

Comment: i want to check how the garment like shirt, fits to a person . for this i want to transform cloth into person's body shape. i am not getting as how to do it.......... i think thinplatesplineshapetransformer will be helpful. but i am not understanding how to use it .

Comment: version for opencv is 3.4.0@RickM

Comment: @KIRAN so is the question that you can't find `ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer` in python or that you don't know how to use it? For the latter, follow the link in the above comments or post another question

Comment: i am not finding , as well as i am unable to understand how to use it